# Isotope - Fluid & masonry layout breaking into 2 columns

Tags: jquery, responsive-design, fluid-layout, jquery-isotope

Not sure whats causing this issue but I have a fluid layout whereby my boxes are 25% in width and I have 4 boxes per row. On resize, I've noticed intermittent errors occur whereby the 4 column is turning into a broken two column. See my video here: http://cl.ly/0s172D303X1M3H1v161z (click View in browser link).

I find the problem is inconsistent across browsers, it works in some browsers but not others. Does anyone have an idea how to fix?

The jsFiddle is here: http://jsfiddle.net/TVXve/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thought I would call attention to your issue over on isotope's github page, as it proved very helpful for me as I encountered this same issue:

https://github.com/desandro/isotope/issues/222

It appears that this is a bug, and you'll need to set your item's width to 24.5%. This then presents an issue with gaps (if you're going for a seamless grid), but should at least help folks get going in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

I've found that both these plugins work best using absolute px values. Have you tried setting columnWidth to a percentage value?

Comment: How might I do this? I changed this line: columnWidth: container.width() / 4 to this: columnWidth: 25% but that broke the layout, I think because I haven't written the JS properly?

Comment: How would you do this @Anriette ??

Comment: Sorry for only replying now, but I've assumed that you have seen this: http://isotope.metafizzy.co/demos/fluid-responsive.html

Comment: Yeah I have but it doesn't give specific percentages as a way to lay out my columns. It only calculates x columns based on the width of the container. Is it possible to give each column a specific width of 25%, like you suggest?

Comment: I would specify `width:25%;` and also a `min-width` as you wouldn't want your elements to go too narrow. Then also, I don't know if you would like your stuff to have margins? Also, what are the error you are getting? Can you see what they are via Web Developer or Firebug?

Comment: Can't see any errors in the console. regarding your code, I already have that width defined for my elements, I thought you meant define the width as 25% in the JS for columnWidth. This isn't going well...

Comment: @erg103 This is probably too late, but to set columnWidth to a % value, you use decimal (so 25% would be columnWidth: .25). Worked for me.